# JuMP constraint specification using a generator

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am working through some of the JuMP example and in particular the multi commodity flow model. I am able to generate a constraint using the below:

```
for r in eachrow(supply)
  @constraint(model,sum(x[r.origin,:, r.product]) <= r.supply)
```

This works fine, however this does not:

```
@constraint(model,sum(x[r.origin,:, r.product]) <= r.supply for r in eachrow(supply))
```

The error thrown is below:

```
Unsupported constraint expression: we don't know how to parse constraints containing expressions of type :generator.
```

This seems odd because if I use a generator in an objective definition it works just fine:

```
@objective(model, Max, sum(r.cost*x[r.origin, r.destination, r.product] for r in eachrow(cost)))
```

So is the takeaway here that objectives take generators, but constraints do not, or is this something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is the takeaway here that objectives take generators, but constraints do not, or is this something else?

JuMP not support the syntax `@constraint(model, lhs <= rhs for arg in iterator)`.

Do instead:

```
@constraint(
    model,
    [r in eachrow(supply)],
    sum(x[r.origin, :, r.product]) <= r.supply
)
```

Your objective function is something different because it is a summation. JuMP does support the `sum(term for arg in iterator)` syntax.